# How to correctly setup a project with multiple folders

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I decided that I want to learn Rust by doing the *Advent of Code* challenges one day at a time. I was thinking that maybe a good way to structure my project would be something like this:

```
-aoc:
-----
|
|-src:
  |-y2021:
  |-y2022:
    |-d1:
    |-d2:
      |-src:
        |-main.rs
      |-target:
      |-mod.rs
      |-Cargo.toml
    |-mod.rs
  |-main.rs
|-target:
|-Cargo.toml
```

The contents of the files so far are as follows.

Inside `aoc/Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "aoc"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
anyhow = "1.0.66"
criterion = "0.4.0"
futures = "0.3.25"
itertools = "0.10.5"
lazy_static = "1.4.0"
serde = "1.0.130"
```

Inside `aoc/src/main.rs`:

```
pub mod y2022;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, Advent of Code!");
}
```

Inside `aoc/src/y2022/mod.rs`:

```
pub mod d1;
```

Inside `aoc/src/y2022/d1/mod.rs`:

```
???
```

Inside `aoc/src/y2022/d1/src/main.rs`:

```
fn simple(i: &[u8]) -> usize {
    ...
}
```

If this way of organizing this project in Rust makes sense, can someone correct the above file. Specifically what should be included where, and additionally how should I test the various days, or if I want to, how can I execute the tests for all the days, or all the years respectively. Should there be a test file somewhere, how do I call these test files, how to I aggregate the tests by day and/or year.

If on the other hand this is not how things should be done in Rust, can you suggest a better alternative of structuring this project?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different binary package for each day, and make `aoc` a [workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html).